# ¿Cómo agrupar y filtrar un DataFrame en pandas de acuerdo a una condición especial?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame como el que muestro a continuación:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                [10009, "AM10","125"], 
                [10007, "AM10","150"],
                [10008, "OP10","135"],
                [10007, "AM10","150"],
                [10010, "OP10","-220"],
                [10008, "AM10","200"],
                [10009, "OP10","-275"],
                [10009, "AM10","500"]])
               columns=['Código', 'Organizacion', 'valor']
```

Lo que necesito es ordenar de manera que los códigos iguales queden continuos y por otra parte filtrar para quedarme solo con los códigos iguales que contengan más de una organización. Con organización me refiero a AM10 y OP10, en el caso que haya un código igual pero con la misma organización se debe excluir con el filtro y obtener algo como se muestra a continuación:

```
df_agrupado = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                [10009, "AM10","125"],
                [10009, "OP10","-275"],
                [10009, "AM10","500"] 
                [10008, "OP10","135"],
                [10008, "AM10","200"]])
               columns=['Código', 'Organizacion', 'valor']
```

Espero recibir ayuda, gracias.

Comment: No se entiende bien a qué llamas "grupos". El resultado de un `groupby()` no es lo que muestras, ya que lo que resulta del `groupby()` es un conjunto de dataframes más pequeños, uno por cada Código, que después se deben agregar con alguna otra función. Si no, por ejemplo, ¿con qué valor te quedas de la columna `valor`? ¿El primero del grupo? ¿La suma? ¿El promedio? Y qué entiendes por tener más de una organización? ¿Quieres decir más de una diferente, o vale que sea la misma repetida?

Comment: Por otro lado cuando dices "obtener algo así" no se entiende el resultado ¿Por qué aparece repetido tres veces el código 10009 y dos veces el 10008? ¿No debería aparecer cada código una sola vez una vez se han agrupado por códigos?

Comment: Tienes razón, no es agrupar precisamente, lo que necesito es ordenar los códigos iguales pero que en el "grupo" que se ordeno se tenga mas de una organización, es decir, AM10 y OP10, no me sirve dos códigos iguales pero con la misma organización.

Comment: Pues he quedado más confundido. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo sería el dataframe resultado partiendo de tu dataframe de entrada? No es necesario que lo escribas como código, basta que pongas como texto la tabla resultante. Asegúrate de que el ejemplo que pones cumple con las caracteristicas que pides (tener dos organizaciones diferentes con el mismo código) para que se pueda entender qué operación estás explicando.

Comment: Mira, ya edite la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que buscas podría ser algo así:

```
df.groupby('Código').filter(lambda x: len(set(x['Organizacion'])) > 1)
```

Es decir:

- Agrupamos por `Código` -> `df.groupby('Código')`
- Filtramos los grupos dónde hubiera más de una `Organizacion` -> `len(set(x['Organizacion'])) > 1`

Comment: Excelente, era lo que necesitaba, de hecho ya había probado esa linea de código pero me faltaba el set, muchas gracias.